# Problems Sending CDATA to PHP With HttpRequest in C#

Tags: c#, php, httpwebrequest, cdata

I'm trying to upload values from a C# application to a PHP script via POST, but the php script seems to be ignoring escaped entities.

```
public static Stream GetStream(string postData, string file)
        {
            try
            {
            HttpWebRequest HttpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(remoteServer + "/" + file + "?");

            //ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
            byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

            HttpWReq.Method = "POST";
            HttpWReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            HttpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;
            HttpWReq.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

            Stream newStream = HttpWReq.GetRequestStream();
            newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            newStream.Close();
            //Get the response handle, we have no true response yet!
            HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)HttpWReq.GetResponse();
            //Let's show some information about the response
            Console.WriteLine(WebResp.StatusCode);
            Console.WriteLine(WebResp.Server);
            Console.WriteLine(WebResp.ResponseUri.ToString());

            //Now, we read the response (the string), and output it.
            Stream Answer = WebResp.GetResponseStream();
            return Answer;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I call

```
System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(content);
```

on the fields of the POST data that contain CDATA but the PHP script still does not handle the & amp; and & quot; properly. For example, passing the string

```
user=a&amp;P&password=lol
```

would produce

```
user=a
amp;P=
password=lol
```

instead of the intended

```
user=a&amp;P
password=lol
```

Answer (score 0):

Yout don't want to use `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(content);` Consider using the [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx) instead